# data.tables: comparing two datasets

Tags: r, dataframe

I just finished to write my R Montecarlo simulation when I discovered using data tables rather than data frames is much quicker. I am trying to switch to data frames, but I cannot translate the following piece of code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(b.dt)) {
  for (j in nrow(a.dt):1) {
    if (b.dt[i,]$condition1==FALSE 
            && b.dt[i,]$b.x1 < a.dt[j,]$a.x1) {
          a.dt[j,]$a.x1 = b.dt[i,]$b.x1
      break
    }
  }
}
```

where `a.dt` and `b.dt` are two data frames, and `a.x1` and `b.x1` are two variables with the same name in the two data frames. Is there anyone that could help me? I have not set any key so far...

Comment: I've voted to close and send to Stack Overflow (don't do this yourself); also for your other question.  For when it gets there - you will get better answers (easier for us to understand your problem) if you can turn this into a reproducible example - eg add a few lines of code that set up dummy objects with the right names.  It's difficult to see exactly what your problem is but there is certainly a more efficient way to do this in R.  And the answer may not be more about using vectorised operations than it is about data frames.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to post to stack overflow myself but apparently posted to the wrong list. Sorry for the mistake. What should I do bnow, just wait on the stack overflow list? Thanks again, Matteo